# soap solution for php

Tags: c#, php, web-services, soap, wsse

i have problem with calling a Web service in php, the Web service written in c # language.
i have sample code in c# that work correctly, this code use System.ServiceModel.ClientBase.

```
ServiceReference2.ExternalClient t = new ServiceReference2.ExternalClient ();
            t.Endpoint.Binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(500, 0, 0);
            t.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(500, 0, 0);
            t.Endpoint.Binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(500, 50, 0);
            t.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
            t.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = txtUserName.Text;
            t.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = txtPassword.Text;
            string ds = t.GetTransfer(txtDate.Text);
```

i test nusoap and soapclient but i get error messages (bad request or Error Fetching http headers ).

my problem is same as [WSSE PHP SOAP Client Header function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350691/wsse-php-soap-client-header-function-call) and my WSDL like [WSDL](http://www.voilacomcel.com/voilaws/VoilaComcelWS.svc?wsdl)

Comment: What's your PHP code like?

Comment: This is a C# proxy, you have to write your own PHP proxy mate

Comment: php Code : $soapclient = new nusoap_client( 'http://ip:port/ExternalServices/?wsdl]' );
  $soapclient->setCredentials( 'user' , 'pass' );
  $soapclient->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';
  $response = $soapclient->call( 'GetTransfer' , array('2013/02/01') );

Comment: A service client is sometimes called a proxy. If the PHP client is giving errors, put the PHP code in your question. To debug this: use Fiddler and comparison PHP and WCF's messages.

Comment: i have use Fiddler and see that c# request encrypted. in dotnet request encrypted with certificate key. i find [wse-php code](http://code.google.com/p/wse-php/source/browse/soap-wsse.php) and will test it.